# Homotopy between two paths in a path connected space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show that any two paths in a path connected space,are homotopic ( homotopic not path homotopic) ,any help?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** $[0,1]$ is contractible. So any path is homotopic to a constant one. Can you elaborate from here ?

Comment: So any path is homotopic to  a constant one , so any two paths are homotopic to two different constant paths , since we're in a path connected space , I can find a  path between these two constant paths and we are done , is this true ?